# Standard way to define expressions in .NET application's UI?

Tags: c#

Perhaps somebody has *the* answer to the following conceptual question:

I am writing a (relatively trivial) application which takes records from a table (every line is a record, the colums are the fields), processes the records, and then writes the new records to a new table.

The problem is that the specification (i.e. how the output records look like and how they are computed) will change all the time and that the users do not have much experience with programming.

I would like to make the application configurable in the UI, i.e. I would like to enable the users to specify expressions like

```
x * y - 3
```

or

```
z.Substring (2)
```

somewhere in the UI (similar to Excel, where you can give formulas for cells).

Question: What is the best language for specifying simple mathematical, boolean, and string expressions?

I have considered the following:

- allow the users to enter PowerShell code
- allow the users to enter C# code
- writing a parser myself

But all that seems to me extremely complicated. Do you have a better idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is a pretty simple language to use. I'd recommend giving the user a list of source columns and allowing them to specify a transform function in javascript, which you could then evaluate at runtime via a library such as [Jurassic](http://jurassic.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Calling%20a%20JavaScript%20function%20from%20.NET&referringTitle=Documentation).

Comment: This looks really good. Now I just have to figure out how to put this jurassic engine into an AppDomain. I'll try. Thank you for this suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

This is job for the [DLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Language_Runtime)! It was designed for dynamic languages. And you have the choice of any language already implemented . I'd just pick [iron python](http://ironpython.net/) and let the users enter the expressions as python statements. It works an absolute dream!

Check out this ultra simple example on how to host the irson python engine in a c# program

http://secretgeek.net/host_ironpython.asp

Comment: Can I prevent the users from doing stupid things like, e.g., accessing the file system?

Comment: Yes just use .net permissions, and load the the script engine into an app domain that has only the permissions you want to give them. Then if they get a security exception - you catch it and tell them off with a big red waving finger!!!!

Comment: @JohnB: Immutable fact - there is no kill switch on stupid. Users will always do stupid things no matter how much you try to prevent it.

Comment: @joel - and .net has security designed just to prevent them blowing their nuts off!!!

Comment: Thanks. I'll try in combination with Jurassic.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Irony](http://irony.codeplex.com/) to create you own expression evaluator with necessary functions. There are already simple expression and Python evaluators in [samples](http://irony.codeplex.com/SourceControl/list/changesets) there.

Comment: Thank you. Maybe an established language is a bit more flexible for my purpose. I'll think about it.