# Eval arithmetic expression windows phone7?

Tags: windows-phone-7

Is there any API for WP7 to get an arithmetic expression in a string and eval it?

Searched for it on google, but nothing comes up..

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [this project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/131587/Building-Linq-Expressions-Dynamically#_rating). Evaluation is done by LINQ, the project does only parsing.

Comment: I don't know anything about Windows Phone 7, but last week I got the hint to try the Jurassic JavaScript engine for a similar problem (not on Windows Phone, though). http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10773499/standard-way-to-define-expressions-in-net-applications-ui

Answer (score 1):

Searching for "C# parse arithmetic from string" I found a good bunch of resources, with [this one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13779/The-expression-evaluator-revisited-Eval-function-i) the most appealing to me. I haven't tried, but I suppose it will compile on WP7.

Anyways, there's always the possibility of building your own parser. You can approach this using expression trees: read about this in [this article](http://math.hws.edu/javanotes/c9/s4.html) (scroll down to the section Expression Trees) (in Java, but explains the concept pretty well and the language is similar enough to C# to be comprehensible).

You can also use the [Shunting Yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting_yard_algorithm), which uses a stack to evaluate the expression. These are only two approachs I remember now, I'm sure there are a lot more. It's harder than using third party libraries, but you can adapt them to your own requeriments.